# python how to create classes in the same file dynamically with name

Tags: python, factory

Say we have a python file with:

```
class A(object):
    def say_hi(self):
        print('hi, I am A')


class B(object):
    def say_hi(self):
        print('hi, I am B')


class F(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def create(self):
        return  ## ???


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = F('B')
    b = f.create()
    b.say_hi()
```

And I want create instance of a class with its name. What the code in F.create() should be?

Comment: `globals()[self.name]()` ?

Comment: @thefourtheye well, If I pass 'A', I want a `A()` if 'B' then `B()`.

Comment: @DSM 'cause I need create instances base on a config file in which the class name is given.

Comment: @mitnk: ah, sorry.  I misread the problem.  I thought you were creating instances and binding them to a given name, but instead you're *accessing* objects.  That's perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def say_hi(self):
...         print('hi, I am A')
...
>>> class B(object):
...     def say_hi(self):
...         print('hi, I am B')
...
>>> class F(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def create(self):
...         return globals()[self.name]()
...
>>>
>>> f = F('B')
>>> b = f.create()
>>> b.say_hi()
hi, I am B
```

Comment: Thanks. I always think it's sort of evil to use `globals` or `locals` in python. So it not evil at all (at least in the code here)?

Comment: @mitnk, If you want to restrict name to `A`, `B`, use something like `{'A': A, 'B': B}[self.name]()`.